# Display names of markers within cluster onmouseover

Tags: leaflet, markerclusterer

I'm trying to display a map with clustered markers, where the user can see the names of the markers within the cluster on mouseover, before clicking to zoom in.

Here is the example I've been working on: http://jsfiddle.net/zvLd54de/4/

The intention is that the onmouseover for London should display the names of the four people living in London, and the onmouseover for Paris should display the names of the three people living in Paris.

So far I've only managed either

- Display the names, but for all the markers within the map view
- Display objects within the cluster, but not the names

**Javascript**

```
markers.on('clustermouseover', function (a) {

    var inBounds = [],
        bounds = map.getBounds();
    children = a.layer.getAllChildMarkers();

    markers.eachLayer(function (marker) {    
        if (bounds.contains(marker.getLatLng())) {
            inBounds.push(marker.options.title);
        }
    });

    document.getElementById('names').innerHTML = inBounds.join('\n');
    document.getElementById('children').innerHTML = children.join('\n');    
});

markers.on('clustermouseout', function (a) {
    document.getElementById('names').innerHTML = ('');
    document.getElementById('children').innerHTML = ('');
});
```

I figure that I somehow need to adapt the if statement so that it only pushes the names within the cluster, but haven't found out how.

If anyone has an idea on how to do this, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

After some more trying, I found a solution.

The updated example can be viewed at http://jsfiddle.net/zvLd54de/5/.

I hope this will be of use for someone else as well.

```
markers.on('clustermouseover', function (a) {

    children = a.layer.getAllChildMarkers();
    var names = [];

    for (i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        names.push(children[i].options.title);
    }

    document.getElementById('names').innerHTML = names.join('\n');  
});
```